# Ant script to remove duplicate lines from file

Tags: ant

I have been trying to find solution in other posts but no one seems to be accurate.
I am struggling to find way to delete duplicate lines from a file.
From ex, a file RTNameList.txt has contents as

```
DBParticipant:JdbcDataSource:appdb
DBParticipant:JdbcDataSource:appdb
HttpType:HttpClientConfiguration:Prochttp
HttpType:HttpClientConfiguration:Prochttp
```

I want only unique line to be written to another file RTNameList-Final.txt .PLease advise best solution using Ant script.
I used below and it does not work.

```
<loadfile srcfile="${ScriptFilesPath}/RTNameList.txt" property="src.file.head">
  <filterchain>
    <sortfilter/>
    <uniqfilter/>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>

<echo file="${ScriptFilesPath}/RTNameList-Final.txt">${src.file.head}</echo>
```

Expected output: File RTNameList-Final.txt should have contents as

```
DBParticipant:JdbcDataSource:appdb
HttpType:HttpClientConfiguration:Prochttp
```

Comment: What is the output that you're getting? I just tried it myself and it works fine. Note that you may need to end your data file with a newline in order for certain filters to work.

Comment: Hi Caustin, Somehow there is no output coming .Ant completes  without doing anything.I mean new file not getting generated with unique line..is there anything missing in my code. ?

Comment: <target name="RemoveDuplicateLines" description="This target call shell script to remove duplicate lines in file and sends output in another file named RTNameList-Final.txt">
<echo file="${ScriptFilesPath}/RTNameList.txt" append="true">${line.separator}</echo>
<loadfile srcfile="${ScriptFilesPath}/RTNameList.txt" property="uniqueLines">
  <filterchain>
    <sortfilter/>
    <uniqfilter/>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<echo file="${ScriptFilesPath}/RTNameList-Final.txt">${uniqueLines}</echo>
</target>

Comment: I looked into it further, and it seems your code contains some invisible characters, making your property name in `loadfile` different from what is being referenced in the `echo` task. At the end of "uniqueLines" in the `echo` task there are the following unicode characters: `U+200C U+200B`. If you're using a keyboard with foreign language input, this is something to watch out for.

Answer (score -1):

Ant is not a programming language. The following example uses an embedded [groovy](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-ant/src/spec/doc/groovy-ant-task.adoc) script to process the file.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── duplicates.txt
└── target
    └── duplicatesRemoved.txt
```

### src/duplicates.txt

```
DBParticipant:JdbcDataSource:appdb
DBParticipant:JdbcDataSource:appdb
HttpType:HttpClientConfiguration:Prochttp
HttpType:HttpClientConfiguration:Prochttp
```

### target/duplicatesRemoved.txt

```
DBParticipant:JdbcDataSource:appdb
HttpType:HttpClientConfiguration:Prochttp
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <available classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" property="groovy.installed"/> 

  <target name="build" depends="install-groovy">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
    <groovy>
      ant.mkdir(dir:"target")

      def dups = [:]

      new File("target/duplicatesRemoved.txt").withWriter { w ->
        new File("src/duplicates.txt").withReader { r ->
          r.readLines().each {
            if (!dups.containsKey(it)) {
              dups[it] = it
              w.println(it)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </groovy>
  </target>

  <target name="install-groovy" unless="groovy.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.3.6/groovy-all-2.3.6.jar"/>
    <fail message="Groovy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: You're right that Ant is not a programming language, but the asker of this question wasn't trying to do anything resembling a programming language in his example. Using Ant's built-in filter types, which are designed exactly for this purpose, would be a much more elegant solution than cooking up a custom Groovy script.

Comment: Hi Mark,Thanks for sharing groovy approach.